# Convert Collection to List

Tags: java, collections

I would like to ask: how do you convert a `Collection` to a `List` in Java?

Comment: You want to *say*? Or do you actually want to *know*? :)

Comment: It seems that you've no idea on how to use general Collections in Java. What about reading a Tutorial? http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html

Comment: So , we are waiting for your story.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you have already created an instance of your List subtype (e.g., ArrayList, LinkedList), you could use the addAll method.

e.g.,

```
l.addAll(myCollection)
```

Many list subtypes can also take the source collection in their constructor.

Answer (score 71):

```
Collection<MyObjectType> myCollection = ...;
List<MyObjectType> list = new ArrayList<MyObjectType>(myCollection);
```

See the [Collections trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) in the [Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

```
List list;
if (collection instanceof List)
{
  list = (List)collection;
}
else
{
  list = new ArrayList(collection);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a new list, and call `addAll` with the Collection.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Sandeep putting it- Just added a null check to avoid NullPointerException in else statement.

```
if(collection==null){
  return Collections.emptyList();
}
List list;
if (collection instanceof List){
  list = (List)collection;
}else{
  list = new ArrayList(collection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use either of the 2 solutions .. but think about whether it is necessary to clone your collections, since both the collections will contain the same object references

Answer (score -3):

`Collection` and `List` are interfaces. You can take any Implementation of the `List` interface: `ArrayList LinkedList` and just cast it back to a `Collection` because it is at the Top

Example below shows casting from `ArrayList`

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Collection c = getCollection();
    List myList = (ArrayList) c;
}

public static Collection getCollection()
{
    Collection c = new ArrayList();
    c.add("Apple");
    c.add("Oranges");
    return c;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you were downvoted because _this won't always work_. Sure, when the `Collection`'s implementing class implements `List` (e.g. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`...), you're fine. But as soon as you try to do something like `Map<Foo,Bar> myMap = new HashMap<Foo,Bar>(); List<Bar> fromMap = (List<Bar>) myMap.values();` everything looks fine at compile time - but when you run it, you get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.List`.

Comment: This is just conceptually totally wrong. You cannot "force" an arbitrary Collection to become a List by casting.